# Combining first function with index in golang/html template

Tags: go, hugo, go-html-template

I'm creating a blog with Hugo. 
i would like to list the first 3 Blog entries. That is not a problem so far.

```
{{ range first 3 .Data.Pages.ByPublishDate }}
```

But i need the index for adding css classes. I do that with this line

```
{{ range $index, $element := .Data.Pages.ByPublishDate }}
```

My problem now is how following. How do I get the index like in the second line of code but still limit the result to 3.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

```
{{ range first 3 $index, $element := .Data.Pages.ByPublishDate }}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* what you are looking for based on your examples is the following:

```
{{ range $index, $element := (first 3 .Data.Pages.ByPublishDate) }}
```